# Rails - Close current DB connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to do some DB experiments in which I reset the DB a few times as part of `Rails runner` script. Here is a simple example:

```
`rake db:reset`
puts User.count
`rake db:reset`
```

This fails with:

```
PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database "my_db" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
```

I understand why this happens. The `User.count` opens a connection so the reset cannot happen. I have tried a few things to close said connection, including calling `close` and `reset_active_connections!`, to no avail. Any idea how I can achieve this? Some other pursuits were not fruitful as well, such as trying to close the connection by passing the process ID to psql.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right call is:

```
ApplicationRecord.connection_pool.connections.map &:disconnect!
```

I simply couldn't find the right method the first time, had to read the AR code in more detail to find it.